# Save the result of an SQL function to a variable within a select statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to take the value given by my function and save it to a variable for the purpose of checking that it is not = '0'.  After extensive searching I cannot find a way to do this that works.  Is it even possible?

```
DECLARE @InspectionID AS VARCHAR(10)
SELECT 
    SYEL.UserComments AS 'UserComments',
    SET @InspectionID = [Silco_Final].[dbo].[GetInspectionIDFromUserComments](SYEL.UserComments)
FROM SY_Edit_Log SYEL
WHERE SYEL.UserCode = 'broberts'
AND @InspectionID <> '0'
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with using functions in SQL Server, but just throwing it out there: can you have `WHERE [Silco_Final].[dbo].[GetInspectionIDFromUserComments](SYEL.UserComments) <> '0'`?

Comment: If at all possible I would change your scalar function to an inline table valued function instead. You will gain some serious performance boost from that.

Comment: I'm not even sure what that is but I'll definitely look into it.  Thanks Sean!

Comment: Post your scalar function and I will see if we can convert it for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you not call the function directly in the where clause?

```
SELECT 
    SYEL.UserComments AS 'UserComments',
FROM SY_Edit_Log SYEL
WHERE SYEL.UserCode = 'broberts'
AND [Silco_Final].[dbo].[GetInspectionIDFromUserComments](SYEL.UserComments) <> '0'
```

Comment: Man I never even thought of that... Great call!